# pattern matching with regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I need to write a program that matches pattern with a line, that pattern may be a regular expression or normal pattern

Example:
    if pattern is "tiger" then line that contains only "tiger" should match
    if pattern is "^t" then lines that starts with "t" should match

I have done this with:

> Blockquote Pattern and Matcher class

The problem is that when I use `Matcher.find()`, all regular expressions are matching but if I give full pattern then it is not matching.

If I use `matches()`, then only complete patterns are matching, not regular expressions.

My code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatchesLooking 
{

    private static final String REGEX = "^f";
    private static final String INPUT =
    "fooooooooooooooooo";
    private static Pattern pattern;
    private static Matcher matcher;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        // Initialize
        pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(INPUT);

        System.out.println("Current REGEX is: "
                       + REGEX);
        System.out.println("Current INPUT is: "
                       + INPUT);

        System.out.println("find(): "
        + matcher.find());
        System.out.println("matches(): "
        + matcher.matches());
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you say "all regular expressios are matching" if you try just one? Please tell us what you expect as output from your program, what it actually prints and what you do not understand. Ohh, and read the java doc for Matcher#matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` given a regex of `^t` would only match when the string only consists of a `t`.

You need to include the rest of the string as well for it to match. You can do so by appending `.*`, which means zero or more wildcards.

```
"^t.*"
```

Also, the `^` (and equivalently `$`) is optional when using `matches`.

I hope that helps, I'm not entirely clear on what you're struggling with. Feel free to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Matcher works:

```java
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

If you're sure there could be only one match in the input, then you could also use:

```java
System.out.println("find(): " + matcher.find());
System.out.println("matches(): " + matcher.group());
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me like OP is confused about the fact that it's returning a boolean and not the matched / found string, or wants to return the matched / found string for that matter.